# Synchronize cronjobs on multiple servers

Tags: java, linux, cron

I am having multiple servers which run the same back-end process in JAVA through cron-tab scheduling.

Earlier I had just one server on which I used to schedule all jobs. This was easier to manage.

Now with increased servers and same process running on all servers with same code base, I want to schedule same cron-jobs on all machines.

I am facing problem, because I have to face lot of trouble and do manual work to change / update all servers if there is a single change.

Can anybody tell me some way to manage scheduling on multiple servers from a common point ? 
Is there any  tool / library / API etc to handle this kind of situation ?

As of now, I am updating / copying (using SCP) JAR on all servers and then restart all processes by individually logging into to each of the servers.

As of now, I will prefer If I do not have to change my JAVA code to manage this(In log run, I can think of that).

However, If I can create a small JAVA application (using Quartz) OR even a shell script to handle scheduling, I will go for it.

I want to be clear that updating JAR on all servers is not my problem, I am working on setup build script(ANT) for that.

My concern is common scheduling code for all servers.

Is there a way to schedule jobs on one server which starts jobs on remote server ? If this happens, I only have to manage scheduling on one server. I wont need to worry about clock sync issues as well ..

Comment: can Quartz scheduler help here?

Comment: You mean, if you can change the code, you have to put the jar (classes) on all the servers .. right?

Comment: Updating question to answer your queries..

Comment: Do you want this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714423/how-to-deploy-and-manage-java-programs-across-servers

Comment: What about using ansible?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a text file, containing the crontab entries in it, and when you deploy the jar file in each server, you can update the crontab at the same time as well, using ant, by running the command `crontab mycrontab.txt`.

Comment: Is there a way to start all scheduled jobs from one server ?

Comment: yes, you can do that as well, using remote shell, or ssh. Too big a discussion for this comment space.